# I am trying to create a rectangle with width = 100 and length = 50 using graphic.py library. I am a bit confused on how to specify the length

Tags: python, user-interface, zelle-graphics

I am trying to create a rectangle with width = 100 and length = 50 using `graphics.py` library. I am a bit confused on how to specify the length. Here's what I have so far:

```
main ():
 win = GraphWin("window", 300, 300)
 rec = Rectangle (Point (250,250), Point(200, 200))
 rec.setWidth (50)
 rec.draw(win)
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, read the [documentation](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/).  `SetWidth` changes the line thickness, not the rectangle size.

The rectangle dimensions are entirely determined by the two opposing corners you specify when you instantiate the object.  I'll change your values to illustrate:

```
rec = Rectangle (Point(300, 200), Point(100, 50))
```

This defines a rectangle with opposite corners at the given points.

The width (x direction) is abs(300-100) = 200

The height (y direction) is abs(200-50) = 150

Does that clear up your confusion?